# `rexxars/react-markdown` plugin usage or alternative for rendering React markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I'm trying to render some html, stored in a DB, and put a  component inside.

It'd look like this:

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown/with-html'; 
const inlineCode = (props) => <Gist id={props.value} />;
const source = '`7df0c9a5d794504a28bd3256b7bf5c4f` <p>asdasdasd</p><h1>title</h1>';
```

ReactMarkdown is used like this:

```
<ReactMarkdown source={source} renderers={{ inlineCode }} escapeHtml={false} />
```

The result is  is rendered properly and the  block is also, but  isn't, the contents are outside of the  block.

If I wrap the whole `source` with a `<div>`, the `<Gist/>` is rendered as text and `<p>`/`<h1>` are rendered properly.

What am I missing? I'm trying to store html with custom components inside, `<Gist/>` is just an example. Suggestions for a (more) suitable library are also welcome. Example ideal `source` I'd like to store in a db and then render in a React component:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <CustomReactComponent/>
    <br/>
    test
  </p>
  <Gist/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found this lib: `https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx`

If your source looks like:

```
const source = `<gist id="yourIdHere" /> <h1>asdasdasd</h1>`;

<Markdown
  options={{
    overrides: {
      gist: {
        component: renderGist,
      },
    },
  }}
>
  {content}
</Markdown>
```

It renders both the `<Gist>` and the normal `<h1>` as `<h1`. Paragraph tags seem to be automatically added if you add line breaks and something like `# Title` is also automatically wrapped.

`<Gist>` in source is converted to lowercase, so it'd only matter for the `overrides` object (lowercase again). Handles all my custom stuff and html predictably.